# BI Publisher Excel Template Report

Tags: bi-publisher

I need to filter Excel Template. which is XML BI Publisher report. 
Report Filter Condition is CATEGORY=('1002')

please advice where to put filter or how to filter the Excel Template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide more details than that.  What is it doing now? What is the expected output? What is the data set?  Custom/Seeded report? Which report? How are you launching the report? Do you want the filter hard coded? If not, where do you want the user to enter the filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the filter in the `for-each` loop of your RTF template. If done that way, *only* those records which match the criteria would make it to the Excel output. The user would have no way of removing the filter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1.) Filter in the SQL, I find this to be the easiest way, but it may not be the best option for this scenario

2.) Filter in the RTF with the for-each statement like @EdHayes3 answered. That would look something like this:

3.) Create a Pivot table that references the your data. Then you can add explicit filters using the normal Excel Pivot table methods. I followed this example with great results: https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/adding-native-pivot-charts-and-tables-to-your-excel-reports .

There may be a way to add a filter to the excel report without a pivot table. If so, I'd love to hear from someone who has done this.